# How often does incense spawn Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-go

I'm looking for the actual timing difference between regular old spawns, and incense induced spawns. Has anyone tested and confirmed this timing?

Answer (score 6):

If you're standing still you can get one every 5 minutes. If you travel at least 200 Meter per minute you can get a Pokemon every minute.

Comment: Do you have a source for that info?

Comment: @glibdud I saw a comment on Reddit a couple of days ago, I tried it out myself and it worked.

Comment: Great... it would be useful if you could find the post and link it in your answer.

Comment: Does this mean we can get one every 2 minutes if we walk 100 meters per minute or must we hit the 200m before the one minute counter is up?

Comment: @Kaivosukeltaja, pokemon will spawn when satisfying both conditions of A) move 200 meters; B) at least one minute.  If you jump 200 meters in one second, you must wait 59 more seconds.  If you move 100 meters in one minute (casual walking speed), you must move another 100 meters before spawn.

Answer (score 1):

Rate of movement does not affect incense spawn rate. It just means you're picking up ambient pokemons in addition to those lured to you. I use incense while sitting in my bedroom, which hardly ever has a spawn. It's close to tared for zero.

In my experience, incense lures about 4-5 pokemons per pot. Most commons. Sometimes an uncommon. Once a rare. Probably RNG as to when and what, but I've never had less than 4 or more than 6 come for an incense.

Comment: This is wrong, and Riley answer is correct. Cf https://gist.github.com/anonymous/077d6dea82d58b8febde54ae9729b1bf#file-game_master_v0_1-protobuf

Comment: No, it's not. All that code shows is that you had those items active while catching, not cause and effect. The whole point of incense and lures is to provide stationary play for pay. You will obviously catch more while walking because you're covering ground while also having incense active, but that is due to covering ground - the incense doesn't "work better" while moving.

Comment: @SarahArcher That is not empirical data that was linked. That is a dump from the official files. And you can tell when Pokémon come from the incense vs. from normal spawns.